# Measure sending data and receiving data

Tags: php, performance, measure

Is it possible to measure how long does it take to data to be sended and how long to be received ?

To measure both of them at the same time, I usualy do something like this :

```php
$start_time = microtime(true);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$end_time = microtime(true);
$execution_time = $end_time - $start_time;
```

I have a slow API call but I don't know if it come from me sending the data of the API sending back the response (sometime 0.3s but sometime up to 6s !)